# Terminal starts with 'sleep' command?

Tags: macos, terminal, sleep-wake, zsh

My machine has *MacOS Big Sur 11.4* with *silicon chips*.
I'm attaching two screenshots here. Whenever I start a new terminal, it appears like this one.
[image: this one].
[image: Termination of terminal]
The terminal shows the running process which is 'zsh > sleep'. Second screenshot shows when I'm closing the terminal window even without running any process manually. Where have I gone wrong? And how should I terminate this process permanently (atleast for the time being for initiation of terminal).

**Please help!!**. I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: I think you'll find that _all_ computers have [silicon chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit) in them :-)  I guess you mean ‘[Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon)’, i.e. Apple's range of [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)-based chips.

Comment: There is a `sleep   .... &` in some of your startup files. Change the configuration of your terminal preferences, so that zsh is executed with the `-x` option. This should show you where the sleep is ... eh ... sleeping; and be glad that the chips of your Apple are made of silicon, and not of potato salad. ;-P

Answer (score 1):

Based on this limited information, my guess would be that you have executing `sleep` somewhere from your zsh config.

To view your zsh config, open `~/.zshrc`:

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

If you find `sleep` in there, you can try removing it and reloading your zsh config with:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: there was no sleep in text editor but i found an unknown line in text. removed it and now the terminal is good. thanks for the heads-up.